# 'FB.api' error on post when using Open Graph in PHP

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am using [Open Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Open_Graph_protocol) where Action Type is "Repin" and Object Types is "Video". When I try to post I get some error. How I can remove this error?

Please see the code below. However, I have looked again and again on Open Graph action and object. In the error console, I am getting the response `HTTP//1.1 200 OK 1857`.

```
<?php
    require 'data/facebook/src/facebook.php';

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    ));

    // See if there is a user from a cookie
    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    if ($user) {
        try {
            // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        }
        catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
            $user = null;
        }
    }
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <title>OG Tutorial App</title>
    <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# xxxxxxxxxx:                        http://ogp.me/ns/fb/xxxxxxxxxxx#">
        <meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
        <meta property="og:type"   content="<namespace>:<action>" />
        <meta property="og:url"    content="<#### My URL ######>" />
        <meta property="og:title"  content="Sample Video" />
        <meta property="og:image"  content="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxximage.jpeg" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            ########### MAIN FOCUS ON THESE BELOW LINES ###############################
            function postCook()
            {
                FB.api(
                    '/me/<namespace>:<action>',
                    'post',
                    {<graph object>: 'http://xxxxxxURLxxxxxxxxxxx' },
                    function(response) {
                        //alert(response.responseText);
                        console.log(response);

                        if (!response || response.error) {
                            alert('An error occurred.');
                        }
                        else {
                            alert('Cook was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
                        }
                });
            }
            ###################################################################################
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>
                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
                    window.location.reload();
                });
                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
                    window.location.reload();
                });
            };
            (function() {
                var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
                e.src = document.location.protocol +
                        '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
                document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
            }());
        </script>
        <h3>Stuffed Cookies</h3>
        <p>
            <img title="Stuffed Cookies"
                 src="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.jpeg"
                 width="200"/>
        </p>
        <br>
        <form>
            <input type="button" value="Cook" onclick="postCook()" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: See the code under "MAIN FOCUS ON THESE BELOW LINES" as I commented above. I am getting alert('Error occured'); Thanks for your interest on my question.

Comment: The HTML is not [well-formed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_element). The <title> tag should be within the <head> tag.

Comment: The ending brace, }, after the two *FB.Event.subscribe*'s does not have a corresponding start brace, {.

Comment: What is output to the console as a result of the line "console.log(response);"?